# A new DotVVM Web Project throws Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Internal.RequestPathBaseCookieBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotvvm

I download extension for Visual Studio for DotVVM framework and create a new .net core project.
In the wizard, I chose Azure Active Directory Authentification as Identity option.
When I run the application, the load ends up with Internal Server error.
I found Exception in output Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Internal.RequestPathBaseCookieBuilder'.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to update package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect to latest version 3.1.3.

Comment: Thank you, lifesaver! I hade the same issue with IdentityModel. It took me a whole week to found your solution. Thanks again!